# How to improve speed when making documentation

Tags: xml, informatica, informatica-powercenter

**TL;DR: In what way can I automatize the process of extracting info from PowerCenter mappings and workflows, as to not copy paste every single box one by one.**

I would like to ask for help from people with more experience than me with this tool, because asking arround in my office the methodology is, roughly, like this:

1) Take a previous, "properly" redacted document that describes the mapping, and go section by section editing whatever was written with the following (I will make up an example):

2) Open the Designer/Workflow Manager, localize the appropiate mapping/workflow, go to each input, open it, copy its name, go to Word document, paste, go to the Designer, copy the description, go back and paste it, and do this for every single input and output for the mapping.

2.5) Next, go to the appropiate session, copy each section one by one into the Word (description, properties, components, whatever is there). Next, copy each and everyone of the parameters used of the mapping, create a table, paste the info, and keep this way back and forth for about 30 to 90 pages.

**My idea up to this point:**  I dump the mapping and workflow as an xml in a file, open it with notepad++, make up a script, or several, that automatize as many extractions of useful info from the xml as possible. There are a couple of problems with this approach:

1. The amount and variety of info of the xml is enough to make the problem non trivial.
2. I am not proficient enough to make this easily. A complete solution, if feasible, would take hours/days/weeks, so I was thinking about starting with small tasks and either combine what I manage to get over time, or make them more robust, but this might not be the most efficient approach.

*I can't believe no one has had trouble when making documentation for powercenter before me, that's mostly why I am asking.*

Edit: I add the following information, which I've found but not tested (not sure I will ever be able to, since the computers have very limited access to both programs And the internet, but if any final option were to work, I might propose it, and if anyone else sees this, it might prove useful to someone else). As of now, I don't think any solves the problem, but I could be wrong.

Different options found in different threads in the oficial Informatica forums:

-ICC utility to obtain sources and targets, it can automatically parse HTML -> it should be able to make something to visualize. It could also be used as a middle step

-An easy way to obtain input and output port is reading the xml generated searching by CONNECTOR tag and filtering by your mapping. 
    This will provide you a full list of FROMFIELD FROMINSTANCE to TOFIELD TOINSTANCE.

-You can obtain the relationship inside a mapplet if you filter by mapplet name instead of mapping.

-Informatica Metadata Manager (MM) which generates automatica linage documentation for all PowerCenter mapping from source to target including Oracle or PL/SQL Stored Procedure linage. This feature is native to Advanced Edition Power Center.

-You can also use PowerCenter Mapping Architect for Visio.

Comment: Hey, I did have the exact thought process, and had built a VB based tool few years back to create documentation from an Informatica mapping xml. It works pretty well with most simple and moderately complex mapping. It outputs an Excel with source to target column mapping with all transformation logic. It does have certain limitation though, e.g. extracting logic from advanced transformations.

Comment: I faced similar problem but for Workflow level. I was thinking of writing a Java code to parse the XML. However, in my case, it was very difficult to accomplish, As in some places, I had inline query written in Pre/Post SQL tasks, in some places, the partitions query was different for each partition etc. Trying to fit all these use cases in a code was difficult, so I spent some time and did it manually.

Comment: @Samik - do you by any chance have that tool with you now?

Comment: @Utsav but would you say that a mix of both techniques would be useful? I spent some time yesterday reading about parsing XML, one of the options would indeed be Java. So maybe even if not every possible case (I don't even know how many can be, but I figure at least a few dozens), it might take some of the bulk away? That's my hope, but on the other hand I also fear it's a bit primivite for this amount of info

Comment: @Samik in your experience, was the effort worth it? Did you learn some other way to do things, or do you have any piece of advice if I were to try the task from scratch?

Comment: @monkeyintern Yes the effort is definitely worth it. It is now used in several projects and accounts in my company. I still use it, whenever I had to analyse or review a mapping developed my somebody else, or need to find a dependency (another feature). It is a small tool (around 2500 lines of code) in VB. If you start building something like it, you have to first understand the mapping xml very well. Also, you have to take special care for reusable transformations, maplets as remain outside the <mapping> tag.

Comment: @Utsav I would not be share it right now due to company policy. However, I am working on similar a open source solution in Java, I hope to publish publicly in the coming months.

Comment: monkeyintern- Yes I agree with you. Do bulk with a tool and later use manual inputs if needed.
@Samik - Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm using: https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/xml_analyzer

And the on-line version: http://powercenter-xmlanalyzer.appspot.com/

The live version will not be able to analyze large, complex XMLs as it's hosted site with quite strict limitations.

Comment: Wow, this looks really promising!!! Now, ON to get permissions to install it... By any chance do you know of any place where screenshots showing the result may exist, as to show it to my boss(es) as proof? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of screenshots do you mean? The online version is a live one, you can check the sample report (http://powercenter-xmlanalyzer.appspot.com/xmlAnalyzerSample) or just throw any dummy XML at it. Let me know if there's anything you'd need.

Comment: No, like some pages show demos or videos the tool working. I can't access the page you provided from work, but thanks for the link, it is very helpful to know this exists

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Informatica forum... why not just make a mapping to read in the extracted xml and spit out the sections you need into a flat file, or better yet, build up the full document section you need and then you just cut and paste once

Comment: For the first part, I'm not sure (nor I have enough experience) if the mapping would be enough by itself. The documentation does not always have the same fields, nor the same requirements, so it should be either very advanced/complex or take into account a lot of different things. As for the second part, similarly, I don't know how to solve that, since the sections of the document aren't up to me and there are a number of different ones (for example, one wf might only have database (STG), while others have that and DWH, that type of things).

Comment: 2) For the input and output names and descriptions the mapping xml is enough and you can extract all the info into a couple of blocks ready to paste. 2.5) For getting info from the session, using the workflow xml, the default session config appears in one nice neat section and any session level overrides appear within the affected session which has been overridden for that  config. The parameters are all together in another block - extract the workflow / mapping xmls and have a nosey around. Problem is that theres no point in any of this effort if your requirements dont have any consistency

Comment: Yeah, the more documents I do the less I see in which way I could convey the raw info into something more useful for me. That last point about consistency nails it. Maybe with time I will se a more abstract way of solving this :S